# If $n$ is composite, then it has a factor $a$ with $1 < a < n$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-explanation, divisibility, factoring

> If $n$ is composite, then it has a factor $a$ with $1 < a < n$.

$n$ is composite $\implies n$ has a factor $a$ with $1 < a < n$ is shown as follows:

As $a | n$, there is a $b$ such that $n = ab$.

But $b$ cannot be $1$ as $a < n$. *(If $b = 1$, then $n = a$, which we cannot have.)*

*Statement in parentheses is mine*.

So this proves that $a < n$. But, from what I can tell, it does not prove that $1 < a$?

Am I correct in thinking this? If so, then how would we complete the proof by proving that $1 < a$?

Clarification is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Proof by contradiction or contrapositive?  If it didn't, it'd be prime.

Comment: Hi @Randall. Just to be clear, are you confirming that the proof is incomplete; that is, it doesn't show that $1 < a$?

Comment: No, just being not-helpful (suggesting an alternate path).  Regarding your argument, you seem to assume that $a$ divides $n$.  But, how do you know that such an $a$ exists?  I think you have to carefully parse what your definition of composite is.  I think to many, this would be the **definition** of composite, not a proposition to prove.

Comment: @Randall This isn't my proof; I just added the part in the brackets. So the first problem with this proof is that it has not showed that such an $a$ exists? What about showing that $1 < a$? As far as I can see, the proof hasn't shown this either? Please clarify.

Comment: What is your definition of “composite.” You seem to assume what you are trying to prove.

Comment: ^what I was trying to say.

Comment: I can’t figure out what you mean by the “statement in brackets.” There is no obvious brackets around any text

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Again, this is **not** my proof. I just thought that it was incomplete, and so I posted it here for feedback.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews *(If $b = 1$, then $n = a$, which we cannot have.)*

Comment: Well, if you don’t give us a definition, we can’t tell what is wrong with the proof.

Comment: Oh, those are parentheses, not brackets.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Oops, sorry. Thanks for that.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I don't know the definition. This is my professors proof in the lecture notes, and he did not define the term before using it.

Comment: Can someone please address my main question: Am I correct in saying that the proof does not show that $1 < a$?

Comment: Usually the $definition$ of "$n$ is composite"  is that $n$ has a factor $a$ with $1<a<n$. Which is what you are trying to prove. I suggest you ask the prof what his def'n of composite is.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Yes, I think there's something not right about this proof (or, perhaps, the way it's done is just extremely confusing).

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove that

$n$ is composite ⟹$n$ has a factor $a$ with $$1<a<n$$

Your assumption is that $ n$ is composite and you want to prove that $n$ has a factor $a$ with $$1<a<n$$

You are assuming that there is an $a$  such that $n=ab$ and so far you have shown that $a<n$.

You want to show that $a>1.$

Well, if the only positive factors of$ n$ are $a=1$ and $b=n$, then $n$ must be prime.

Thus $a$ must satisfy  $$1<a<n$$

Comment: If n is composite it must have factors < n, by definition!

Comment: Hi Mohammad. Thanks for the response. But it seems that this still doesn't show that we cannot have $a = 1$, $b = n$?

Comment: If the only possible values for a and b are $1$ and $n$ then $n$ is prime.